# Select Customers Who Purchased In X Month AND Y OR Z Month

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select

I have a table that stores when customers have purchased something, and I am trying to find all customers who have purchased something in August 2016 (`X`) AND October 2016 (`Y`) OR November 2016 (`Z`) --- `X AND (Y OR Z)`.

I need the output to display the customers name, and the date of the purchase.

Customers are identified by `ALL_CUSTOMER_ID` and the date is stored in an `ARRIVAL_DATE` field (`Ex: 05-AUG-16`) in the table `PMS_FOLIO`.

Customers names are stored in the `NAME` field in the table `ALL_CUSTOMER`.

Comment: what dbms is being used?

Comment: @vkp I am using Oracle SQL Developer to try and query this data.

Comment: So they need to have purchased on ((August AND October) OR (August AND November) ) AND NOT (October AND November), right?

Comment: @FDavidov edited OP to clear the confusion.

Comment: In that case, remove the **either** word is it implies **XOR**.

Comment: @FDavidov Ah okay. I've edited the OP again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_CHAR()` for the month, and the `HAVING` clause to filter :

```
SELECT t.cust_id
FROM purchases t
GROUP BY t.cust_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DateField,'yyyymm') = '201608' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DateField,'yyyymm') IN ('201610','201611') THEN 1 END) > 0
```

This will also return customers that had purchases both in October and November. If you want only purchases on one of them then :

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DateField,'yyyymm') = '201608' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DateField,'yyyymm') = '201610' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       MAX(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(DateField,'yyyymm') = '201611' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
```

Comment: I'm using Oracle, it's added in the tags now :)

Comment: @WolfieeifloW Adjusted .

Comment: I forgot to add it's specific to 2016, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, it works! How do I go about adding more fields to the output though?

Comment: Depends on the field:)

Comment: I need to display the `ARRIVAL_DATE` and the customers actual name, pulled from table `ALL_CUSTOMER` field `NAME`, linked by `ALL_CUSTOMER_ID`. If you want we can [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127301/discussion-between-wolfieeiflow-and-sagi).

Comment: Wrap this query with parentheses and join it to the desired tables as a simple join query.

Comment: Having trouble with this. Is it not just `SELECT NAME FROM ALL_CUSTOMER JOIN PMS_FOLIO ON (ALL_CUSTOMER.ALL_CUSTOMER_ID = PMS_FOLIO.ALL_CUSTOMER_ID) WHERE(<Your Query>);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by` and `having`. Your question provides neither sample data nor a database tag, but here is the idea;:

```
select customerid
from t
group by customerid
having sum(case when month(date) = 8 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when month(date) in (10, 11) then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

You probably want to include the year as well in the comparison.

Comment: He said _and either October or November_, meaning `XOR`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Yes, I need to include the year as well.